# Receiving error with support-v7:25.1.0 in gradle on compile

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to work with a source code I have received lately, but unfortunately I am not able to compile it due to flagged dependencies that are not working.

This the gradle that is showing the problem:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project(':calendar') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':colorpicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':datetimepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':timezonepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':ex:chips') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }


        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile project(':calendar')
    compile project(':colorpicker')
    compile project(':datetimepicker')
    compile project(':timezonepicker')
    compile project(':ex:chips')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'external/ex/common/java'] // NOTE: this includes external/ex/common/java!
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

I am currently getting the errors shown in the pictures attached:

[image]
[image]

Knowing that I have updated the **Android platform SDK to 25** and **Android Support Repository** and **Google Repository** as suggested in other posts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade the Gradle dependencies to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

and add this in android part

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

Comment: I get the same error for com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1